# CSS/HTML slider with text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an image/text slider using only css and html. It would be similar to [this one](http://css-tricks.github.io/AnythingSlider/simple.html#&panel1-1).

Is there a way that I can incorporate text to the left of the images? I want it to be laid out with a small image to the right side of the page and a text description to the right of the image.

Comment: With css/html only? Good luck.

Comment: do you have the code you work on?

Comment: I am not opposed to using some Javascript as well, I would just prefer to keep it html/css.

Comment: This is the type of slider that I have been playing around with: http://codepen.io/rilwis/pen/InhHE

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify this to suit your needs. Found at: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-image-slider

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('http://html5css3demos.bplaced.net/css3-slider-v3/websymbols-regular-webfont#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:400,700);

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/dark_wall.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 1px;
}

h1 { color: white }

#slideshow-wrap {
    display: block;
    height: 320px;
    min-width: 260px;
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 12px rgba(255,255,240,1) solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 500%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -moz-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    -o-transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li {
    width: 20%;
    height: 320px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li>img {
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):not(.show-description-label) {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -45px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(200,200,200,1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s;
    transition: background-color .2s;
}

#slideshow-wrap label:not(.arrows):active { bottom: -46px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~label[for=button-1] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~label[for=button-2] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~label[for=button-3] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~label[for=button-4] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~label[for=button-5] { background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1) }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-1] { margin-left: -36px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-2] { margin-left: -18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-4] { margin-left: 18px }

#slideshow-wrap label[for=button-5] { margin-left: 36px }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: 0 }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -100% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -200% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -300% }

#slideshow-wrap input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~#slideshow-inner>ul { left: -400% }

label.arrows {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgb(255,255,240);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

label.arrows:hover { opacity: 1 }

label.arrows:active { margin-top: -23px }

input[type=radio]#button-1:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-4, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-5 {
    right: -55px;
    display: block;
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1, input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2, input[type=radio]#button-4:checked~.arrows#arrow-3, input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 {
    left: -55px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: scaleX(-1);
    -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

input[type=radio]#button-2:checked~.arrows#arrow-1 { left: -19px }

input[type=radio]#button-3:checked~.arrows#arrow-2 { left: -37px }

input[type=radio]#button-5:checked~.arrows#arrow-4 { left: -73px }

.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 260px;
    font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz';
    z-index: 1000;
}

.description input { visibility: hidden }

.description label {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    background-color: rgba(255,255,240,1);
    position: relative;
    left: -17px;
    top: 00px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    z-index: 5;
    color: rgb(20,20,20);
}

#slideshow-inner>ul>li:hover .description label { opacity: 1 }

.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~label { opacity: 1 }

.description .description-text {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,230,.5);
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    z-index: 4;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: rgb(20,20,20);
}

.description input[type=checkbox]:checked~.description-text { opacity: 1 }
```

```html
    <div id="slideshow-wrap">
        <input type="radio" id="button-1" name="controls" checked="checked"/>
        <label for="button-1"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-2" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-2"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-3" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-3"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-4" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-4"></label>
        <input type="radio" id="button-5" name="controls"/>
        <label for="button-5"></label>
        <label for="button-1" class="arrows" id="arrow-1">></label>
        <label for="button-2" class="arrows" id="arrow-2">></label>
        <label for="button-3" class="arrows" id="arrow-3">></label>
        <label for="button-4" class="arrows" id="arrow-4">></label>
        <label for="button-5" class="arrows" id="arrow-5">></label>
        <div id="slideshow-inner">
            <ul>
                <li id="slide1">
                    <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/3/3yiC6Yq.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-1"/>
                        <label for="show-description-1" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Flower power</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide2">
                    <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/40Ly3VB.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-2"/>
                        <label for="show-description-2" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Golden sunset</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide3">
                    <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/0/00kih8g.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-3"/>
                        <label for="show-description-3" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Flower power again</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide4">
                    <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/2/2rT2vdx.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-4"/>
                        <label for="show-description-4" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Stormy coast</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="slide5">
                    <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/8/8k3N3EL.jpg" />
                    <div class="description">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="show-description-5"/>
                        <label for="show-description-5" class="show-description-label">I</label>
                        <div class="description-text">
                            <h2>Splash!</h2>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```